# Dart - Receive data from TCP server

Tags: dart, sockets, tcp

In Python, I use following codes to receive data from a TCP server:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((lib_parameters.HILINUX_IP, lib_parameters.HILINUX_PORT))
s.send(b"")
fragments = []
while True:
    chunk = s.recv(4096)
    if not chunk:
        break
    fragments.append(chunk)
square_data = b"".join(fragments)
s.close()
```

The TCP server is something like (in Python):

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (IP, PORT)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        data = b"\x00\x01"
        connection.sendall(data)
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

I need codes with the same functionality... I have read the documentation [Dart Socket class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.3/dart-io/Socket-class.html), but I don't know who to receive data...

Answer (score 0):

The core idea is to use [listen()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.3/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) method of Socket class.

```
listen(void onData(Uint8List event)?, {Function? onError, void onDone()?, bool? cancelOnError}) → StreamSubscription<Uint8List>
```

In `onData()` callback, get data from the server.

Sample codes:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  final socket = await Socket.connect("192.168.1.68", 40000);
  print('Connected to: ${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');
  var fullData = BytesBuilder();
  socket.listen(
    (Uint8List data) {
      fullData.add(data);
      print("RECV DATA: ${data.length} B");
      print('Server: ${data.length}');
    },
    onError: (error) {
      print(error);
      socket.destroy();
    },
    onDone: () {
      print("DONE: full data ${fullData.toBytes().length} B");
      socket.destroy();
    },
  );
}
```